# googlevis $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, googlevis

I've hit the dreaded "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" error. It happens when I add the gvisLineChart. Any suggestions?

```
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)

#this is a dput of a sql query to make the example reproducible. 
#In reality this will be an RODBC sqlQuery result
dataset <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
  value = c(1.68294196961579, 82.4641565111739, 83.3056274959818, 
  6.73176787846317, 5.89029689365528, 2.52441295442369, 4.20735492403948, 
  0.841470984807897, 5.04882590884738, 15.1464777265421)), 
  .Names = c("id", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

ui <- shinyUI(
     plotOutput("motionPlot")
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output[["motionPlot"]] <- renderGvis({

    Line <- gvisLineChart(dataset, xvar=c("id"), yvar=c("value"))     
    plot(Line)
   })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It's very difficult to help without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Sounds like `dataset` isn't a data.frame but we can't run your code to test it.

Comment: I've used the msdb database in this example so that anyone with a mssql db can run it. Any query against any db will reproduce the result. Unfortunately it is a db related question so 'reproducible' would include a reference to a database. Thanks for your interest, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've dput the sqlQuery result to make it reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

googleVis plots aren't quite like regular plots in R. Regular plots produce static images but googleVis produces basically mini-web pages with HTML and javascript data as well. Therefore you should't use `plotOutput`, you should use `htmlOutput` to render them to the page. Also, you don't need to use `plot()` either. This will work with your example data

```
ui <- shinyUI(
     htmlOutput("motionPlot")
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output[["motionPlot"]] <- renderGvis({
        gvisLineChart(dataset, xvar=c("id"), yvar=c("value"))     
   })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I found more examples [here](http://www.magesblog.com/2013/02/first-steps-of-using-googlevis-on-shiny.html) by googling "shiny gvisLineChart". Tested with `googleVis_0.6.1`, `shiny_0.13.2`, `R 3.2.5`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks MrFlick